# In USQL, I keep getting conversion error for NULL even though I am using the nullable type e.g. int?, datetime? etc.

Tags: nullable, u-sql

When I change the type to string, I am fine. But, when I use int?, datetime? etc, sometimes it accepts NULL and sometimes, it fails with the error.

"Problem while converting input string '"NULL"' to proper type."

Comment: Can you please provide a concrete example of a failure? Also, are you passing "NULL" (the string) or _null_ (the value)?

Comment: Passing 'NULL'. Same one in both the places. where the parser accepts and where it does not for int?|31|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|1

Answer (score 2):

If you pass the following file content:

```
31|NULL|1
```

to the following `EXTRACT` expression:

```
@data = 
  EXTRACT a int?, b int?, c int? 
  FROM @file 
  USING Extractors.Text(delimiter:'|');
```

you will get the error message you observe since NULL is treated like a string. The default way to serialize and parse null values with the built-in Extractors/outputters is as no value, e.g., `31||1`. The built-in extractors provide you with a `nullEscape` parameter though. So try:

```
… USING Extractors.Text(delimiter:'|', nullEscape:"NULL");
```